# getting sqlcode=-302 while using CallableStatement in Websphere

Tags: jdbc, websphere

I am using the CallableStatement Class in Websphere java application to make a call to a native SQL procedure. But when the application is deployed an run ,I get an sqlcode of -302
SqlDataException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=3,

I have cross checked the parameters of the SQL SP as well as the java code. They seem to be right. Java coe snippet

protected CallableStatement cs = null;

/* Establishes connection to the DB2 datasource */ 
dbAgent.connectToDataSource(AEUtils.getDataSource());

/* prepares the SP call statement */

cs = dbAgent.createCallStatement
        (DB2StoredProcedure, this.NSPparameterCount);

cs.setString("PA_INSERT_IN", "Y");

This cs.setString("PA_INSERT_IN", "Y"); statement throws a -302. However when I invoke the same SP via., a stanalone java program it works.
Am I missing something here ? (note that dbAgent is an object of a helper class developed inhouse)

Comment: Could you share more details about the error you're receiving? Do you get a ClassCastException? Please post the stack trace for the error.

Comment: Sorry for replying very late. The problem was due to flow control within the program. Its resolved now